# PyTorch Lightning working in One Collab Notebook but not Another

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning

When I am following a Youtube tutorial, my code breaks when they try to import `pytorch_lightning`.  I had a similar problem in my PyCharm environment but it has since gone away, and I am unsure why.

Error provided was

`import pytorch_lightning as pl fails with ValueError: transformers.models.auto._spec_ is None.`

This is my collab notebook : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DeeYFvK7wFsf9VBxjr184VAlulg6M_ly?usp=sharing

I decided to try and see if I can replicate the error using a minimal sub-example in a new notebook : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NiHIoIt8v215-lO8KoHKDSkCuw9W5S6a?usp=sharing

In the new notebook, it imports just fine.  Why is it then in my actual notebook I get an error?

Update : Ending my runtime session, and restarting it, has solved the issue.  However I'd like to know what I did that caused it in the first place, if possible, to avoid having this occur again.

Answer (score 0):

it's a known issue with `torchmetrics==0.7.0`. Until `torchmetrics==0.7.1` will be released, use an older version:

```
pip install "torchmetrics<0.7"
```

Here's the tracking issue: https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/11524